# How to POST a huge string using AJAX and parse it

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post

In my razor view file, I'm making an `ajax` call as follows:

```
var myForm = $("custom-form");

myForm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: surl + "ParseData",
        data: myForm.serialize(),
        success: function (result, status, jqXHR) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ...
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

In my `form` element, I only have one hidden input field which holds a html string. This is what I need to post with the `ajax` call. Once that's done, I also need to retrieve and parse the html string within a Controller.

I know how to pass and retrieve key/value pairs using `ajax` but I'm trying to figure out how to post a html string; especially when it could be quite big. (I'd say it could easily be as big as 25 to 30 pages of text in letter sized format when it's parsed). Also, how can it be retrieved and parsed within a Controller?

Comment: What happens when you try to POST your form currently?

Comment: Is the structure of the string predictable? You may be able to deserialize it into a model. If it contains html tags then you can use http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: POST itself works just fine - I come back to the 'success' condition when it's completed.

Comment: @Ilya.N. - Structure of the string is highly UNpredictable

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with posting the form like this with jQuery. Wouldn't it make more sense to use Html.BeginForm() or Ajax.BeginForm() and POST your model? You've mentioned controller? Are you using Microsoft MVC?

Comment: @nickgowdy - If this approach seems odd, I don't blame you. TBH, I inherited someone else's problem at work and I'm not even a .NET developer. Anyway, I really just need to know if posting and retrieving html string with the given approach is viable or not. And yes, it is based on MVC.